# MLT query video_codecs not listing libx264

Tags: ffmpeg, mlt

Querying video codecs does not list libx264 as an available codec

```
[terry@localhost ~]$ melt -query video_codecs | grep 264
  - h264_nvenc
  - h264_v4l2m2m
  - h264_vaapi
  - nvenc_h264
  - h264
  - h264_cuvid
```

But I can use it in a command such as:

```
melt avformat:DarkStar.webm -consumer avformat:output.mp4 acodec=aac vcodec=libx264
```

and it works successfully.
This is causing a problem with kdenlive.  When selecting **Render** and choosing the format **MP4 - the dominating format (H264/AAC)** the render option is disabled with the error Unsupported video codec: libx264.

kdenlive checks the profile codec against the list obtained from MLT using:

```
Mlt::Properties vcodecs(mlt_properties(consumer->get_data("vcodec")));
```

which seems to get the same list as query video_codecs.

For info here is what ffmpeg says about the codecs:

```
[terry@localhost ~]$ ffmpeg -codecs | grep 264
ffmpeg version 4.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.0 (PCLinuxOS 9.3.0-1pclos2020)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --enable-pic --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --incdir=/usr/include --extra-cflags=-I/usr/include/nvenc --disable-stripping --enable-postproc --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --disable-encoder=vorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-libdc1394 --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libcelt --enable-libopus --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libtwolame --enable-libxavs --enable-frei0r --enable-libmodplug --enable-libass --enable-gnutls --enable-libcdio --enable-libpulse --enable-libv4l2 --enable-avresample --enable-opencl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libaom --enable-sndio --enable-libdav1d --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-version3 --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libxvid --enable-decoder=atrac3 --enable-decoder=atrac3p --enable-libwebp --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-nonfree --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
 DEV.LS h264                 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (decoders: h264 h264_v4l2m2m h264_cuvid ) (encoders: libx264 libx264rgb h264_nvenc h264_v4l2m2m h264_vaapi nvenc nvenc_h264 )
```

Software versions:

mlt-6.20.0

ffmpeg-4.3

x264-1.157.20190309

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were changes in ffmpeg 4.3 which required MLT to be rebuilt against it.

Answer (score 0):

`libx264` is not a codec, its an encoder implementation of a codec. use `ffmpeg -encoders | grep 264`

Comment: Thanks.  How would I get that info from MLT?